# hyperlink <a> not changing color on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make it so when a user hovers over  the background color changes. The problem is that after I set it all up, only my header is changing the background color, nothing else.

```
<tr>
  <td class="near">
    <a href="../index.html"class="near_place">
      <img class="related_photo" />
      <h4 class="nearby"> adfadfad </h4>
      <span class="related_info">asdfadfadfaf</span>
    </a>
    ...
```

CSS:

```
a.near_place {
  width: 200px;
  height: 65px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline;
}

a.near_place:hover {
  background: #DEDEDE;
}

h4.nearby {
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  display: inline;
}

img.related_photo {
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  border: solid thin #DFDFDF;
  margin-right: 3px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span.related_info {
  width: 150px;
  height: 54px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
}

td.near {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto; 
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `background-color: #DEDEDE;`

that "-color" is important

Comment: You can use the background shortcut and only specify the color, leaving off the url/position/etc.

Comment: This is incorrect - I checked it in jsfiddle; the problem was wrapping block elements in an inline element.  `background: #DEDEDE;` is valid shorthand

Comment: @Sam Dufel It's valid shorthand, but he was overriding a property that was stopping it from displaying correctly. Also while it may be a "sin" to wrap a block element with an inline element *to you*, it is perfectly valid html5: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/  - Thanks for voting me down though :/

Comment: @Grillz - If you look at the title of the page you linked, you'll see that it says 'block-level links' - not 'inline links wrapped around blocks.'  Also, it's written in the HTML specification that inline elements should only contain other inline elements and data.

Comment: @Sam Dufel The very first sentence: "One new and exciting thing you can do in HTML 5 is wrap links round “block-level” elements." Or you can just read the spec http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element - "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections..." Now I've provided two links backing up my statement (which solved the question here), so I hope this is clear to you.

Comment: @Grillz - I apologize if I'm sounding argumentative, but you're misunderstanding - I'm not at all saying you can't wrap anchor tags around blocks.  I'm saying that when you set a CSS style for an anchor to display it as an inline element, and then place blocks inside of it, it won't render the way you expect it to.

Comment: @Sam Dufel Understood, and I do want to get this clear on my end as well. The way I understand it is that an anchor tag is inline by default, so when he is saying display:inline on his a tag it's actually not doing anything different than if he had left that line out. I guess it doesn't matter much in the end, I just didn't like being downvoted for something I am sure was correct.

Answer (score 0):

don't see any reference in css to anything other than background so whatever you want to change needs to be specified with a color

Answer (score 0):

More specific rules might help, for instance try changing style for tags inside of your  tag:

```
a.near_place:hover img.related_photo {
}
```

Or

```
a.near_place:hover * {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're committing the sin of wrapping (a) a block element and (b) a floating element inside an inline element.  Trying changing your `<a>` element to `display:block;`.